# Ambiguous definition of generators in dihedral groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

In *Dummit and Foote*, the dihedral groups $D_{2n}$ are defined first as the groups with rotations (generator $r$) and axial symmetry over the line between the center and the point 1 (generator $s$). The two generators verify $s r = r^{-1} s$.

For $D_{2n}$, one can assign a number in $[1, n]$ each point (which move under transformation), and a number in $[1, n]$ to each positions (which stay fix under transformation). The initial state considered is that the point $k$ in at the position $k$ for each $k \in [1, n]$.

This generators $r$ and $s$ can then be understood in two different ways. And this seems to be related to the "Problem of alias and alibi" as mentioned in the [Companion to Lang's Algebra](https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/.C.to.L/), end of p.8.

**Convention A**:

- $r$ transforms each point to the next point
- $s$ performs the axial symmetry which keep fixed the position 1
- acts by alibi

**Convention B**:

- $r$ transforms the point at each position to become the point at the next position
- $s$ performs the axial symmetry which keep fixed the point 1
- acts by alias

I tried for $D_8$ to perform $r s$ and compare it to $r^{-1} s$ considering both conventions. I have found that:

- The equality $s r = r^{-1} s$ is verified for both conventions.
- The final state after applying $s r$ is different in both convention.
- In both conventions you only apply rigid-body motions of the points.

So I have two questions:

- What is the convention used in Dummit and Foote (or what is the convention generally implied) ?
- Does it even matters ? In the sense that whatever convention is chosen, you will end up with $s r = r^{-1} s$ in every $D_{2n}$ ? Are both conventions just convenient graphical representations ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your explanation correctly, but if I am, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: As written it appears convention A and B are identical. Can you elaborate on the differences you perceive here?

Comment: I agree, I cannot see any difference between A and B.

Comment: $D_n$ is the symmetries of the $n$-gon. I think if you reflect upon this, you will realise both your conventions are exactly that.  Whether one rotates a point to another point, or one rotates a point to the position previously occupied by another point, the rotation is surely the same.

Comment: I think this topic is discussed in "Companion to Lang's Algebra", I included a link to it.

Comment: (+1) Related: [Active and passive transformation - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the commenters that I can't see a difference between your conventions. I'm also not sure what you mean by position. I think you're making a distinction without a difference.

I've written this answer to attempt to clarify things.

A common choice of representation of the dihedral group $D_{2n}$ as rotations and reflections of the plane is the following:
$$r\mapsto R_{2\pi/n} 
= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos 2\pi/n & -\sin 2\pi/n \\
\sin 2\pi/n & \cos 2\pi/n
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and 
$$s \mapsto S=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 
0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

These matrices represent a rotation counterclockwise by $2\pi/n$ and a reflection over the $x$-axis respectively, which appears to be the action you're trying to describe in words.

**Edit**

Having read your updated question and the wiki article linked in the comments by Calum Gilhooley, 
[active and passive transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_and_passive_transformation), I have a better idea of the question you're trying to ask, I think.

You're asking whether we regard the dihedral group as acting on the points or the coordinate system, right? The answer then is that it doesn't really matter, a representation of a group can be regarded as doing either, since matrices can be regarded as either representing an action on points in a vector space or a change of coordinate system for the vector space. However, in mathematics, and particularly group theory, we almost always regard the representation as acting on the points of the vector space rather than the coordinate system.

Comment: This would be the convention A in my post, then. I added a link to the "Companion to Lang's Algebra" who might better describe my problem :).

Comment: So what is convention B? Can you be explicit? Either a matrix representation or a picture or something?

Comment: Convention B would be that S depend on the previous transformation applied. The axis would rotate with each rotation, as it would be dependent of the position of the point 1.

Comment: @vkubicki That doesn't sound like a coherent description of a representation of a group. A representation of a group is a group homomorphism $\phi: G\to \operatorname{GL}(V)$ for some vector space $V$. You can't have $\phi(s)$ be two different things at once depending on what came before it.

Comment: I don't yet enough about group representation. My understanding came from the basic description at the beginning of Dummit and Foote with a simple "physical description". Then I found the material on alibi and alias on the Companion to Lang's Algebra and finally someone in the comments to the question linked it to active and passive transformations. Besides, both conventions satisfy the generators relation on the small case I tried it on. So if you say that convention A is more aligned with group representation, I guess that is an argument in favor of it.

Comment: @vkubicki I read the wiki article linked in the comments, I think I understand your question better now, and have edited to reflect that. Hopefully my edit will be more useful.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very clear!